# NewtonSoftJson DateTimeZoneHandling.Local net 3.1 vs net 5

Tags: asp.net

I've migrated my application from net 3.1.8 to net 5.0.5

I'm using this configuration for pascal case and to automatically convert dates to local time:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddNewtonSoftJson(opts => {
        opts.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
        opts.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        opts.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local
}
```

My post action looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExportData([FromForm] DateTime reportDate)
{

}
```

Date format is `2021-04-15T21:00:00.000Z`. In 3.1.8, `reportDate` was equal to `2021-04-16`, but now in 5.0.5 it converts to `2021-04-15` and 9PM.

Any suggestions for the fix?

Comment: You're using JSON.NET extensions so the .NET Core version doesn't matter. You're asking for `DateTimeZoneHandling.Local` though. Perhaps you're running this code on different machines, with different timezone settings? It looks like one machine is at +3:00, and the other at UTC

Comment: I'm testing on a development machine (client + server). Before switching to net 5, it was ok. `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` depends on `Newtonsoft.Json` 12.0.2.

Comment: That doesn't mean the local timezone isn't different. Maybe you used a VM? Or manually changed the timezone settings? `2021-04-15T21:00Z` is 2021-04-16T00:00` in Eastern Europe (+3:00). The **only way** to get `2021-04-15 and 9PM.` from `2021-04-15T21:00:00.000Z` is to run the code at UTC

Comment: Switching back to 3.1.8 works ok. Maybe it's one of the model binders that have changed.

Comment: I can convert it to local time: `var date = reportDate.ToLocalTime()`

Comment: I think I've found were the problem was - the default `DateTime` model binder. Apparently for the `[FromForm]` attribute, the model binder sets DateTime.Kind to Utc.
For the `[FromBody]` attribute it uses json.net's serializer's global settings.
I've created a custom model binder for the first case to fix the problem.

Comment: What happens when you use the built-in JSON serializer instead of JSON.NET ? Do you get consistent behavior?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use net's default serializer, because of my front end framework (it has a parser linked to json.net). Also I'm not sure how to apply global settings for the default one.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, apparently the `DateTime` model binder is different in 5.0.5.

Writing a custom model binder solved the problem for the `[FromForm]` parameter.

Looks like complex type parameters are handled by the Json.Net serializer global settings (`opts.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local`); so no problems there.